High swap consumption during database backup with mariabackup

Hello
We are experiencing a swap consumption problem when backing up our database.
Every evening at 01am we run the mariabackup command and during the process swap usage rises sharply until it reaches 100% and only drops back to normal usage around 10am at best.
The VM has an Alamalinux 8.4 OS, around 60GB RAM and a 4GB SWAP partition.
Normal” resource utilization (excluding backup) is around 70-80% of RAM and 70-80% of SWAP.
The vm.swapiness value has been set to 0, but this does not change the SWAP consumption. RAM usage remains fairly stable outside or during evening backups.

Do you have any idea why SWAP is used so much during backups?
Is this normal? Do you have any recommendations?
Best regards,
Kevin Pemonon

Is there any fancy options in the [mariabackup/xtrabackup] section(s) in your ini file? Your server used a quite reasonable amount of RAM so backup should too. If no options was overridden by some section indeed.

Thank you for your answer Kondybas, we will check the config files

Hey, unfortunately, it is hard to tell given the info that you have shared. Can you check the memory utilization of the mariabackup process or its child processes? Other processes that run on that node? I wonder if there is a difference in the memory utilization across the processes. Total used memory looks stable on the graph but maybe there’s some change that result in some of the memory pages being stored in the swap file.

Thanks for your answer Severalnines. For your information, this is a three-node cluster managed with maxscale. Backup is performed on the master. Most of the swap and ram are used by mariadb.
It seems that the increase in swap during the backup process is caused by the tar command used to archive the result of the mariabackup command.

after checking, it seems that the swap overconsumption is caused by the tar command issued after the mariabackup to archive the command result.
Is there any way of obtaining a tar file directly from the mariabackup command?
For your information:

the mariabackup command takes about 5 min, while the tar command takes about 1 hour.

the possibility of increasing the swap to 8GB should be tested.

in our context, deleting the swap partition is not possible for administrative reasons.



mariabackup couldn't be streamed to the tar on the fly cause mariabackup  writes to the several files simultaneously, in parallel. So the sequential backup+tar is unavoidable. tar itself doesn't consume a lot of RAM but if you have some compression involved, say xz, RAM consumption could be enormous.

N.B. Deleting of the swap partition is a bad idea as far as swap is a last resort in the case of RAM outage.

Thanks for your answer Kondybas
